# nVidia driver on Linux, and the need to reset the resolution on reboot

Tags: resolution, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm using Ubuntu and I have a Samsung Syncmaster 2232 monitor, which is a 22" widescreen. I also have version 185.18.14 of the nVidia video driver, running on an XFX GeForce 6200.

My problem is that while the driver works at my monitor's native resolution, (1680x1050) for some reason it always goes back to 1600x1024 whenever I reboot the system. I've used the nVidia software to save the settings, but it always goes back. It's even in /etc/X11/xorg.conf as 1680x1050, so I have no idea why it goes back to the other resolution.

Any hints?

Comment: This should be tagged "xorg" as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you use nVidia's display manager, make sure that you start it with root permissions, **and** tell it to write out the changes to the xorg.conf

Comment: Ok, I'll try that but that doesn't explain why the 1600x1024 resolution is **not** in the xorg.conf file.

Comment: its likely that for some reason EDID is probing your monitor wrongly during X starting, and the automatic resolution thing it does ( check your log ) is deciding the resolution doesn't work in advance wrongly.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. @Kent: searching for EDID (with grep -i no less) or 1600 in my boot log doesn't come up with anything at all.

Comment: Can you post the device section of xorg.conf?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some comments, it is possible that your monitor outputs incorrect EDID information which may confuse X.

Try adding

```
Option "UseEDID" "FALSE"
```

to

```
Section "Device"
```

section of your xorg.conf. (Specifically, the one with an Identifier you are using; presumably the one with Driver "nvidia".

This requires that you manually enter information (HorizSync/VertRefresh, DisplaySize) for your monitor. I'm not sure if this has changed with modern LCD panels; I still use a CRT at home...

If this doesn't work you should remove that line; most monitors get this right.

Answer (score 0):

I could be terribly wrong here, but I don't think that your xorg.conf is to blame.

Check the settings in System -> Preferences -> Display

If that menu entry is not present, it is either disabled in the menu or the required package is not installed. You need to run `gnome-display-properties` which is included in the `gnome-control-center` package.

And if you are not using Gnome, just forget everything I just wrote.

Comment: I am using Gnome, but I don't have "Display" under System -> Preferences.

Comment: Try running gnome-display-properties from the shell.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, install the gnome-control-center package which contains the display applet.

Comment: Typically if the nvidia binary driver is installed, opening this menu will refer the user back to the nvidia settings app.